# Memory Leak with $timeout in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, memory-leaks

I've noticed I get a massive memory leak when I use the $timeout function in my angularjs application and I NEED help to figure out why!

This is a relatively large app and it has multiple layers.

Controller A is the main controller.  Access a couple root scope variables and makes some service requests to a database.  This all seems to be working properly.  Controller A's template has a ui-view.  This ui-view can display Controller C, D, or E.

Controller C, D, and E do similar things but do NOT contain the timeout function.

I've noticed that over time this blows up, eventually killing the browser. Somehow, I'm not destroying stuff properly and I'm not sure how.  Please help!!

If you need more details let me know!

Controller A:

```
defaultApp.controller("controllerA", function (ConfigClass, $scope, $log, $timeout,
$state,  utilityServices, dataReadingService) {
try {
    //initial variable
     //initial variable
    $scope.caplLineupCoilCnt = 0;
    $scope.caplLineupCoilTotalLength = 0;
    $scope.error = "";
    $scope.activeTab = sessionStorage.caplLineupActiveTabName == undefined ? 0 : sessionStorage.caplLineupActiveTabName;
    $rootScope.showRunnableConnections = false;
    $scope.Refreshing = false;
    $scope.$parent.GetCraneStatus();

    $scope.changeStringerView = function () {
        $rootScope.caplStringerView = !$rootScope.caplStringerView;
    }

    //assign default filter value
    $scope.caplViewFilter = localStorage.caplViewFilter == undefined ? '4' : localStorage.caplViewFilter;

    //Get rewrap status.
    dataReadingService.getCaplWrapStatus().then(function (results) {
        if (results[0][1] != undefined) {
            $scope.wrapStatusTime = new Date(results[0][1]).getTime();
        }

        if (results[0][0] == "0") {
            $scope.reWrap = "Off";
        }
        else if (results[0][0] == "1") {
            $scope.reWrap = "On";
        }
        else if (results[0][0].toString() == "2") {
            $scope.reWrap = "No Go";
        }
        $scope.eskidCoils = results[1];
        $scope.rewraps = results[2];
    });

    dataReadingService.getWestFullStatus().then(function (results) {
        var resultDate = new Date(results);
        var old = new  Date(1972,1);
        if (resultDate > old) {
            $scope.fullWest = results;
        }
    });


    $scope.togglePopover = function (popup) {
        var popupElement = document.getElementById(popup);
        popupElement.classList.toggle("show");
    };

    //assign active tab and write to session storage
    $scope.assignActiveTab = function (tabIdx) {
        $scope.activeTab = tabIdx;
        sessionStorage.caplLineupActiveTabName = tabIdx;
    };

    //filter columns
    $scope.updateFilterSetting = function (idx) {
        localStorage.caplViewFilter = idx;
    };

    $scope.showRunnableOptions = function () {
        $rootScope.showRunnableConnections = !$rootScope.showRunnableConnections
    }

    //read empty bins, CAPL lineup cnt, CAPL lineup total length
    dataReadingService.getCaplEmptyBins()
        .then(function (result) {
            $scope.emptyBins = result;
        }, function (excp) {
            $scope.error += excp.data.Message + ' | ';
            $log.error(excp.data.Message);
        });
    dataReadingService.getEmptyBins("tek")
        .then(function(results){
            $scope.emptyBinsTek = results;
        },function(excp){
            $scope.error += excp.data.Message + ' | ';
            $log.error(excp.data.Message);
        });
    dataReadingService.getCaplLineupCoilCntAndTotalLength()
        .then(function (result) {
            $scope.caplLineupCoilCnt += result[0];
            $scope.caplLineupCoilTotalLength += result[1];
        }, function (excp) {
            $scope.error += excp.data.Message + ' | ';
            $log.error(excp.data.Message);
        });
    dataReadingService.getCaplRunnableCoilCnt()
        .then(function (result) {
            $scope.caplRunnableCoilCnt = result;
        }, function (excp) {
            $scope.error += excp.data.Message + ' | ';
            $log.error(excp.data.Message);
        });
    dataReadingService.getCaplNonRunnableCoilCnt()
        .then(function (result) {
            $scope.caplNonRunnableCoilCnt = result;
        }, function (excp) {
            $scope.error += excp.data.Message + ' | ';
            $log.error(excp.data.Message);
        });
    dataReadingService.getCaplStringerCoilCnt()
        .then(function (result) {
            $scope.caplStringerCoilCnt = result;
        }, function (excp) {
            $scope.error += excp.data.Message + ' | ';
            $log.error(excp.data.Message);
        });


    var getNoSteelStatus = function () {
        dataReadingService.getNoSteelStatus().then(function (results) {
            $scope.noSteelStatus = results;
        });
        dataReadingService.getCommitsNoSteel().then(function (results) {
            $scope.noSteelCommits = results;
        });

    };
    getNoSteelStatus();

    $scope.commit = function (selection) {
        dataReadingService.commitNoSteel(selection).then(function (results) {
            getNoSteelStatus();
        });
    }

    $scope.orphanize = function (coilNo) {
        $scope.success = false;
        $scope.failure = false;
        dataReadingService.orphanizeCoil(coilNo).then(function (results) {
            if (results == "Success") {
                $scope.success = true;
            }
            else {
                $scope.failure = true;
                $scope.orphanHover = results;
            }

        });
    };

    $scope.TestRunLUMessage = function () {
        dataReadingService.TestRunLUMessage().then(function (results) {

        });
    };


    $scope.ExportToExcel = function () {
        dataReadingService.ExportToExcel().then(function (results) {
            return true;
        });

    }


    var TOFunction = function () {
        if ($state.current.name.substring(5, 9) === 'capl') {
            $state.reload();
            $scope.Refreshing = true;
        }
    }


    $scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
        console.log("State Destroyed");
        $timeout.cancel(timeout);
        console.log("Timeout Canceled");
    });



    //refresh state
    var timeout = $timeout(TOFunction, 15000);    //Usually 5 minutes but reduced to 15 seconds for testing.
} catch (excp) {
    $scope.error += excp + ' | ';
    $log.error(excp);
}
});
```

UPDATE:

I made a change to my code to cancel the timeout.  But sitting on the page for a minute moves the memory in the Chrome Task manager from 160mb to 630mb.  Am I still doing something wrong?

Comment: try using a profiler. you should also clear your timeout on destroy.

Answer (score 1):

When you change routes before the timeout is called, the timer is still running, and this creates a closure that prevents the garbage collector from freeing the view's memory.

You need to clear the timeout when the [`$destroy`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#event-$destroy) event is broadcastedusing [`$timeout.cancel()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout):

```
var timeout;

$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
  $timeout.cancel(timeout)
});

timeout = $timeout($scope.TimeOut, 15000);
```

Comment: This might work for switching tabs, but doesn't seem to help when I'm just sitting on the page.  Check my update.  Did I do something wrong?

Comment: The only thing in the code is the timeout, and that's cleared. Other things you can try, is cancel pending API requests. Try to limit the problem to a single controller, by removing elements and/or using the profiler.

Comment: I added my full controller code.  Maybe this will help?